# PHP "Undefined" errors after installing Laravel in VS Code

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code

All I did was create a new Laravel project with `composer create-project laravel/laravel games_review` and I started getting these errors without touching a single line in the PHP code.

[image: An example of the error shown]

I also see a VS Code error that says

```
The PHP Language Server server crashed 5 times in the last 3 minutes. The server will not be restarted.
Source: PHP IntelliSense (Extension)
```

I have PHP in my path and when I type `php -v` into the console, it says

```
PHP 8.0.3 (cli) (built: Mar  2 2021 23:34:05) ( ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64 )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.3, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

In VSCode, I have three PHP extension packs installed

1. PHP Intelephense
2. PHP Debug
3. PHP IntelliSense

I have nothing related to PHP in my VSCode `settings.json` file

Comment: what do you expect from vs code? know all laravel classes? did you install laravel plugin in it?

Comment: what's the exact name of this plugin

Comment: use PHPSTROME if you want to more IntelliSense or you need to buy `PHP Intelephense` for vscode

Comment: problem is related to PHP IntelliSense extension, so maybe disable it or look for it's compatibility with php 8?